# Determining issues based on incomplete error messages

Tags: r, debugging, runtime-error

This is a quick and possibly simple question. When I source a particular `R` module, it appears to run normally, but in the end of the **output** it greets me with the following message:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) :
```

I did some search on StackOverflow and found several questions with the same output. However, it is always accompanied with additional information, like "object 'A' not found". Since in my case this information is missing, I don't know where the problem is (to **debug** that area). The only idea I came up with was to call `traceback()`. Its **output** doesn't seem to be very helpful (unless I'm unaware of something):

```
5: stop() at eda.R#303
4: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
3: eval(ei, envir)
2: withVisible(eval(ei, envir))
1: source("~/diss-floss/analysis/eda.R")
```

Any **ideas**? What is the correct **approach** to handling such situation in `R` in general? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, what's the code "at eda.R#303"? If nothing there is apparent, stick a `browser` at/in front of that line?

Comment: To supplement what Roland mentions, `eda.R#303` is telling you to look at file `eda.R` at line number 303.

Comment: Oh, my bad! I missed the line number in the output - thank you, @Roland. I guess, I just proved that working overnight has negative correlation with attention span (N=1) :-). Will check the code and hopefully post an answer soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, based on very fast feedback from @Roland and @BrodieG (**much appreciated!**), I found what the issue was. It is one of the most ridiculous software defects I've ever seen: I just placed a `stop()` call at that line to prevent sourcing the subsequent section of the code (*disable* it **temporarily**). So, if you look at it from my perspective, it is a *feature*, rather than a *defect*. :-) Anyway, much relief and onto the next set of issues!

Comment: Next time use `stop("Intended interruption of script")`.